# Не получается вставить 2д изображение в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я делаю игру на Unity, и я хотел сделать спидометр для машины. У меня получилось импортировать само изображение спидометра в папку Assets, сделал объект image, у изображение сделал его "Texture Type" Sprite(2D and UI), но изображение все равно не встает в строку Source Image
что надо делать в такой ситуации?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Измени `Texture Type` у картинки на `Default`. Компонент `Image` не совместим с `Sprite (2D and UI)`